# cronjob vs daemon in linux. When to use?

Tags: linux

There are advantages making a process daemonized, as it it detached from the terminal. But the same thing also can be achieved by cron job as well. [ Kindly correct me if not ]

What is the best requirement with which i can differentiate the scenarios when to use cronjob or daemon process?

Comment: It is not a silly question. I wish I could vote to un-close it.

Comment: You are right @MarkR, but its not programming related; and better suited for unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In general, if your task needs to run more than a few times per hour (maybe <10 minutes) you probably want to run a daemon.

A daemon which is always running, has the following benefits:

- It can run at frequencies greater than 1 per minute
- It can remember state from its previous run more easily, which makes programming simpler (if you need to remember state) and can improve efficiency in some cases
- On an infrastructure with many hosts, it does not cause a "stampedeing herd" effect
- Multiple invocations can be avoided more easily (perhaps?)

BUT

- If it quits (e.g. following an error), it won't automatically be restarted unless you implemented that feature
- It uses memory even when not doing anything useful
- Memory leaks are more of a problem.

In general, robustness favours "cron", and performance favours a daemon. But there is a lot of overlap (where either would be ok) and counter-examples. It depends on your exact scenario.

Answer (score 13):

The difference between a cronjob and a daemon is the execution time frame.

A **cronjob** is a proccess that is executed once in a while. An example of cronjob could be a script that remove the content of a temporary folder once in a while, or a program that sends push notifications every day at 9.00 am to a bunch of devices.

Whereas a **daemon** is a process running detached from any user, but wont be re-launch if it comes to end.

Comment: Daemons/services can also be run as the logged in user. You can place user services under `~/.config/systemd/user/` and control them with `systemctl --user`. Not sure if that fits into the definition of "daemon", but the user services run in the background, and they're not under direct user control, exactly like system services (but they run in userspace).

Comment: Daemons/services can also be automatically restarted on failure (and at least on my Ubuntu system, many daemons do this by default, e.g. syslog and sshd).

Answer (score 13):

If you need a service that it permanently available to others, then you need to run a daemon. This is a fairly complicated programming task, since the daemon needs to be able to communicate with the world on a permanent basis (e.g. by listening on a socket or TCP port), and it needs to be written to handle each job cleanly without leaking or even locking up resources for a long time.

By contrast, if you have a specific job whose description can be determined well enough in advance, and which can act automatically without further information, and is self-contained, then it may be entirely sufficient to have a cron job that runs the task periodically. This is much simpler to design for, since you only need a program that runs once for a limited time and then quits.

In a nutshell: A daemon is a single process that runs forever. A cron job is a mechanism to start a new, short-lived process periodically.

Answer (score 1):

A daemon can take advantage of it's longevity by caching state, deferring disk writes, or engaging in prolonged sessions with a client.

A daemon must also be free of memory leaks, as they are likely to accumulate over time and cause a problem.